# Convergence of Truncated and Subsequenced MA($\infty$) Processes with Square Summable Coefficients

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, convergence, moving-average

Let $X_t=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \phi_j \varepsilon_{t-j}$ be an MA($\infty$) process with square summable coefficients. We know that if we truncate the process at $n$, creating the sequence:
$$X_{t,n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \phi_j \varepsilon_{t-j},$$
then $X_{t,n}$ converges to $X_t$ in mean square as $n$ approaches infinity.

Now, suppose we have a subsequence of the coefficients $(\phi_j)_{j=0}^{\infty}$, specifically $(j_k)_{k=0}^\infty$, and consider:
$$Y_{t,K} = \sum_{k=0}^K \phi_{j_k} \varepsilon_{t - j_k }.$$
Can we say that $Y_{t,K}$ converges to $X_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi_j \varepsilon_{t-j}$, as $K \to \infty$ ?